# Bootstrap example pages not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to use Bootstrap; I am downloading example pages to build off of from the Bootstrap website. When I launch them, however, they look quite crummy in my Chrome browser.

For example, when I load the narrow-jumbotron page, the jumbotron spans the entire screen... What am I doing wrong? I have the css, js, and font folders inside the folder that I've saved the `narrow-jumbotron.html` page in.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the source url or path of the css and other files. Possibly this is creating problem.

Comment: I do always delete the "../.." that exists before the css/boostrap.min.css but it still doesn't make the page load exactly as found on Boostrap site

Comment: Give the link from where u are downloading the example.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly ensure that you have downloaded bootstrap.min.css and jumbotron-narrow.css.
Place them in the folder you are having the html file.

After that find the following 2 statements in your html file.

```
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Replace them with these lines:

```
 <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kunjan; immensely helpful

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's probably is a path issue. When you download the original bootstrap framework, you'll have a /css and a /js directory. How your new html files get access to those places depends on where you put those directories. I'm going to assume you have some bootstrap test area. Let's just call this your main bootstrap area or core file area, whatever.

After you set that up, you probably went back for the other download which has the /examples directory buried within it. The files in there are set up to deal with being a few directory levels down. When you went into the /examples directory folder, did you copy over the whole /examples branch? Or just one set of the example files?

Let's try this just as one example just to try to get things working. Then once you get it working if you want to mess with directory / folder organization and file paths, that's fine.

1. Go find the examples/theme directory, wherever you put it. In this /theme directory rename index.html to theme.html
2. Take the theme.html and theme.css out of your /examples/theme directory and put them in the root directory of wherever you have your bootstrap's root index.html file. Now your file paths to CSS files and such should be set to match what the index.html file is doing.
3. Go into the theme.html file and look for the lines with the ../../dist/css/ as suggested earlier.
4. But make them look like this...   "css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
5. This should now have these files getting called from the correct places. This alone should work for you.
6. There's still one issue though. You'll see in the theme.html file a link to "../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"
7. You could just ignore this, but to really have things all in order, you need to get that path right. So, go find your original download of the examples and get the whole /assets folder and sub-folders copied into wherever you have your bootstrap root; that is /assets should be at the same level as /css and /js.
8. Once again then, fix the link to look like this "assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"

This will hopefully get you going and give you a clear and obvious sense of how the file paths work. If you like going forward, put things into better directory / folder structures and re-do the paths. Remember if you wanted to on a real web server, (local or remote), you can always use virtual paths from the root so you don't have to keep track of the levels everyplace for such files.

In any case, I did just test this and ideally it will work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just place bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js in the same folder as carousel folder for example.

Then fix the path of the js file to this:

```
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And fix the path of the css file to this:

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete "integrity" part

Instead of this:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Make:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

As integrity attribute checks whether code was changed.
That might help.

Answer (score -1):

As of 2022 and the BootStrap version v5.2 the way to fix it is to copy paste the  `bootstrap.min.css` file you get when you download the ready-to-use compiled code to the  example folder you want it in and then change these lines from

`<link href="../assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

TO

`<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

This must do the trick

Comment: you answering on a question from 2014 that didnt even really meet the SO guidelines even at that time. Adding your answer does not add anythign usefull to the already existing answers nor does it really attempts to answer the question. Besides that, there have been many noticible changes from Bootstrap from 2014 (v3.2) to 5.2. There even have been many changes from the 4th version. So addign a link to Bootstrap-5 is not practicble nor usefull in this case.

Comment: @tacoshy When i searched on google i got redirected here  so i am pretty sure many have got the same problems as well so it really does not matter if its v3.2 as long as i have mentioned it to be 5.2 I have clearly mentioned everything so that they don't get confused